# Send string with Wifi-Direct between two devices

Tags: java, android, string, message, wifi-direct

I'm currently working on an application in which I got two devices searching for peers and connecting to them automatically, but now, I want them to exchange some messages (both devices will be saving different information about something, and then I want them to send the information to the other one) using `Strings`.

I've found some examples on the Internet such as "Wifi-Direct Chat", but I'm new to working in Android and I find this task a little complicated, because they have a lot of different classes and code and it's very difficult to understand. If you have any idea of how could I achieve my objective I would be very grateful.

Comment: I would download and play with the WifiDirectServiceDiscovery sample project. Here is a list of Wi-Fi Direct resources: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wi-fi-direct/uWpuOzHY6y0